# Http put Ionic 3 Not working

Tags: angular, http, ionic3, http-put

Basically this http put will act like a button and switch on a system. On postman, i can just input the URL and it works fine, but when i try to implement it on Ionic App, it doesnt do anything. (Sorry if the codes is unclear)

The following is the HTTP code generated by POSTMAN

```
    PUT (......) HTTP/1.1
    Host: ip
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Postman-Token: 0bad8e4d-e717-015a-e321-d2ee05acc563
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Any Idea how do i implement in an Ionic Angular 4 Application?

```
 data: any;

    toggle(): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });  
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

          return this.http.put('http:/ip/......', JSON.stringify(this.data), options).
map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));


      }
```

There is actually no error whatsoever, but just that nothing happens.

Comment: Have you subscribed?

Comment: What is the value of `this.data`?

Comment: Please show the code of calling `toggle`

Comment: Hh @SurenSrapyan, i did not subscribe, i read most of this.http.put and i follow them.

Comment: @hrdkisback , hi i set data = any as i am not sure what i should add for the body

Comment: @VivekDoshi Hi i did not call it, this is the method when i click on the button.

Comment: Hi thank you everyone, it is working now after i subscribed :) @SurenSrapyan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make http call you should **subscribe** `Observable` , or it won't be called

This is the one of the main diff b/w `Promise` and `Observable`

```
toggle(): Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' });  
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        return this.http.put('http:/ip/......', JSON.stringify(this.data), options).
                map((res:Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => { console.log(data); }) // you are missing this line over here
                .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

}
```

> **Suggestion Note :**
>
> Try to put this code in some service and not in any component
>
> ```
> return this.http.put('http:/ip/......', JSON.stringify(this.data), options).
> map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I am using several URLs, thats why i did not use any service :)